# C++ Age Calculator - Most Efficient Equations for Finding Time Between 2 Dates

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an age calculator in C++ which takes user input for the current month, day, and year, along with the user's birthday, (MM DD YYYY). The rest of the functions are working properly, but I'm having issues with my calculateAge() function.

Can anybody see the problems with my equations in my calculateAge() function, or a way I could make this more efficient?

**EDIT: Full Code**

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main () {

    //declare local variables
    bool valid, validBirthday;
    int cmonth, cday, cyear;
    int bmonth, bday, byear;
    int ageYears, ageMonths, ageDays;
    char answer;
    const int MAXGUESSES = 3;

    //function declarations
    bool enterDate (int&, int&, int&, const int);
    bool enterBirthDate (int, int, int, int&, int&, int&, const int);
    void calculateAge (int, int, int, int, int, int, int&, int&, int&);

    //prompt the user for todays date and invoke the enterDate() function
    cout << "Please enter today's date, ";
    valid = enterDate(cmonth, cday, cyear, MAXGUESSES);

    //if validDate() function doesn't recognize a valid date after three tries
    //the user is alerted
    if (valid == false)
        cout << endl;
    else

    //if the date was valid show the user the date they entered and ask
    //if they would like to calculate their age.
    if (valid == true) {
        cout << "Date entered is: " << cmonth << '/' << cday << '/' << cyear << endl;

        cout << "Would you like to see how old you are? (y/n) ";
        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == 'N' || answer == 'n')
            cout << "OK" << endl;
        else

        //if the user would like to see their age, call the enterBirthDate
        //function and assign the return value to the boolean variable
        //validBirthDate
        if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y') {
            if (validBirthday = enterBirthDate (cmonth, cday, cyear, bmonth, bday, byear, MAXGUESSES) == true) {

            cout << "Date entered is: " << bmonth << '/' << bday << '/' << byear << endl;       

            //call the calculateAge() function to calculate the user's age
            calculateAge(bmonth, bday, byear, cmonth, cday, cyear, ageYears, ageMonths, ageDays);

            //display results
            cout << "You are " << ageYears << " years, " << ageMonths << " months, and " << ageDays << " days old." << endl;

            //display a special result if it is the users birthday
            if (bmonth == cmonth && bday == cday)
                cout << "Happy Birthday!" << endl;
            }

            else
                cout << "You have entered an invalid birth day." << endl;

        } //end if answer is yes

        else //if answe is not yes or no
            cout << "You did not enter 'y' or 'n'" << endl;


    } //end if current date is valid
}
```

**Functions**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//function definition for enterDate() - the function that prompts
//the user for input and parses input into months, days, and years
//and then calls the validDate() function to make sure the entered 
//date is valid.

bool enterDate (int&month, int&day, int&year, const int MAXGUESSES) {

    bool valid;
    int counter = 1;

    bool validDate(int&, int&, int&);

    cout << "Please enter the date as MM DD YYYY: ";
    cin >> month >> day >> year;

    valid = validDate(month, day, year);

    // use the constant MAXGUESSES and the variable counter to
    // allow the user only three tries to enter a valid date

    if (valid == false) {
        while (valid == false && counter < MAXGUESSES) {
            counter++;
            cout << "The entered date is invalid, please re-enter: ";
            cin >> month >> day >> year;
            valid = validDate(month, day, year);

        }

    // if the user reaches the limit of three guesses, alert them
    // and bring an end to the program

    cout << "You have reached the limit for invalid dates." << endl;
    }

    return(valid);

}

// function definition for enterBirthDate() which prompts the user to enter
// their birthdate and invokes the enterDate() function to parse the input and
// the dateBefore() function to make sure the entered birth date occurs before
// the current date entered by the user

bool enterBirthDate (int cmonth, int cday, int cyear, int&bmonth, int&bday, int&byear, const int MAXGUESSES) {

    bool valid;
    bool valid2;

    bool dateBefore (int, int, int, int, int, int);
    bool enterDate (int&, int&, int&, const int);

    cout << "We need to know your date of birth, ";

    // call function enterDate() to prompt the user for input and parse
    // the input into b(irthday)month, bday, and byear

    valid = enterDate(bmonth, bday, byear, MAXGUESSES);

    //if the birth date entered by the user is a valid date, make sure
    //that the birth date occurs before the current date supplied by
    //the user in enterDate()

    if (valid == true)
        valid2 = dateBefore(cmonth, cday, cyear, bmonth, bday, byear);

    return(valid2);

}

//function definition for dateBefore() (invoked by enterBirthDate()  which
//compares variables c(urrent)month cday, and cyear to b(irth)month, bday, 
//and byear to make sure the birthday occurs before the current date supplied by the user

bool dateBefore (int cmonth, int cday, int cyear, int bmonth, int bday, int byear) {

    bool valid;


    //if the birth year is greater than the current year assign the boolean
    //variable 0 (false) to valid, indicating an invalid birth date

    if (byear > cyear)
        valid = false;
    else

    //if birth year is equal to the current year, perform relational operations
    //on the bmonth and cmonth variables to determine which date occured first

    if (byear == cyear) {

        //if the birth year and current year are the same, but the birth
        //month is less than the current month, assign the value of true
        //to the boolean variable valid

        if (bmonth < cmonth) 
            valid = true;
        else

        //if the bmonth = cmonth perform relational operations on bday and cday
        if (bmonth == cmonth)

            //if the bday is less than the cday assign true to the boolean variable valid
            if (bday < cday)
                valid = true;
            else
                //if the bday is greater than the cday assign the value false to valid
                valid = false;
        else

        //if bmonth is greater than the cmonth and byear is equal to the cyear 
        //assign false to valid, indicating an invalid birth day

        if (bmonth > cmonth)
            valid = false;
    else
    //if the cyear is greater than the byear assign the value of false to valid
    if (byear < cyear)
        valid = false;
    }

    return(valid);
}


//function definition for validDate() (invoked by enterDate() ) which uses variables of day, month, and year
//to make sure that the date entered is valid based on month, day, and year variables
bool validDate (int&month, int&day, int&year) {

    //local variables
    bool valid;
    int maxDay;

    //function declaration
    int getLastDay (int);

    //calculate maximum day based on month
    maxDay = getLastDay(month);

    //if the month is less than zero or greater than 12 assign the value false to
    //the boolean variable valid indicating an invalid date
    if (month < 0 || month > 12)
        valid = false;

    else

    //if the month is valid make sure that the day falls inbetween 1 and the maximum day
    //associated with the month entered

    if (month > 0 && month <= 12) {
        if (day > 0 && day <= maxDay)
            valid = true;
        else
            valid = false;
    }

    return (valid); 
}

//function definition for calculareAge(). Invoked by main(), calculate age accept parameters bmonth, bday, byear,
//cmonth, cday, and cyear (by value) to perform calculations and relational operations to determine age. The parameters
//ageYears, ageMonths, and ageDays are passed by reference so they can be output in the main() program.

void calculateAge (int bmonth, int bday, int byear, int cmonth, int cday, int cyear, int&ageYears, int&ageMonths, int&ageDays) {

    //local variable
    int maxDay;

    //function declaration
    int getLastDay (int);

    maxDay = getLastDay (bmonth);

    if (cyear >= byear && cmonth >= bmonth && cday >= bday){
        ageYears = cyear - byear;
        ageMonths = cmonth - bmonth;
        ageDays = cday - bday;

    }
    else

    if (cyear > byear) {
        if (cmonth >= bmonth) {
            if (cday < bday) {
                ageYears = cyear - byear;
                ageMonths = cmonth - bmonth - 1;
                ageDays = maxDay - bday + cday;
            }
        }
        else
        if (cmonth < bmonth) {
            if (cday > bday) {
                ageYears = cyear - byear - 1;
                ageMonths = 12 - bmonth + cmonth;
                ageDays = cday - bday;
            }
            else
            if (bday > cday) {
                ageYears = cyear - byear - 1;
                ageMonths = 12 - bmonth + cmonth - 1;
                ageDays = maxDay - bday + cday;
            }
        }
    }

}

//function definition for getLastDay(), uses the month entered to calculate the maximum
//valid day for that month

int getLastDay (int month) {

    int maxDay;

    switch (month) {
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            maxDay = 30;
            break;
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12:
            maxDay = 31;
            break;
        case 2:
            maxDay = 28;
    }

    return(maxDay);
}
```

Comment: If you can provide a working code (I meant full code), then it would be easy for use to debug.

Comment: I'll add the rest of the code. Originally I only added those 2 functions because the problem I'm having is in the equations to determine the number of days, months, and years.

Comment: The C++ standard library has no date arithmetic, but the Boost library provides two date sub-libraries. It's embarrassing. Almost as embarrassing as Excel's failure to handle dates before 1900 or whenever it was (I forget). Anyway, a main complication is leap years. And another main complication is that a year is not exactly a whole number of days.

Comment: @BrookeElizabeth So, you should not handle leap year here, right? and please, tell what is not working properly. Thanks

Comment: I am ignoring leap years for this program. I'm having bugs with my calculateAge() function, I'm assuming my problem is in some of the equations I've set up, specifically the ones where the current day is smaller than the birth day and the current month is smaller than the birth month (ex. ageMonths = cmonth - bmonth - 1)

Comment: You usually don't need to forward declare the functions in the middle of the others like that

Comment: If give an example of input that does not work as expected, what it should output and what it actually output, it would make things easier too.

Comment: You need to specify in more detail the calculateAge function I think. This will help you wrap your head around it. I suppose you have current date and birthday date and you intend to calculate the difference (name age). Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems your code just fails in cases like: `1 9 2001 y 1 10 2000`.

What about giving a constant value for each day of the calendar?

I modified your `calculateAge()` function and created another function named `getInt()` which gives the corresponding constant value of a date.

So, deducting two dates easily gives us the result. See the code below to be clear.

Feel free to ask anything about it.

#### New getInt function:

```
int getInt(int y, int m, int d)
{
    int ret = y*365;

    //function declaration
    int getLastDay (int);

    for (int i = 1; i<m; i++)
        ret+=getLastDay(i);
    ret+=d;
    return ret;
}
```

#### Modified calculateAge function:

```
//function definition for calculareAge(). Invoked by main(), calculate age accept parameters bmonth, bday, byear,
//cmonth, cday, and cyear (by value) to perform calculations and relational operations to determine age. The parameters
//ageYears, ageMonths, and ageDays are passed by reference so they can be output in the main() program.

void calculateAge (int bmonth, int bday, int byear, int cmonth, int cday, int cyear, int&ageYears, int&ageMonths, int&ageDays) {

    //local variable
    int maxDay;

    //function declaration
    int getLastDay (int);

    int now = getInt(cyear,cmonth,cday);
    int birthday = getInt(byear,bmonth,bday);
    if(now<birthday) return;
    int diff = now-birthday;
    ageYears = (diff)/365;

    diff-=(365*ageYears);

    ageMonths = 0;
    int rest;
    while(1)
    {
        rest = getLastDay(ageMonths+1);
        if(diff>=rest)
        {
            diff-=rest;
            ageMonths++;
        }
        else break;
    }
    ageDays = diff;
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about assigning constant values to the days but that makes the calculations so much more efficient instead of dealing with all of those conditionals I was trying to use. Thank you!

Comment: @BrookeElizabeth Thank you too. If you want to implement leap year, then you may have to modify in `getInt()`, but calculation in `calculateAge()` would remain untouched.

Comment: Upvoted.  In case it is helpful, here are some highly efficient algorithms for these types of calculations.  But they follow the basic idea you've laid out here.  These algorithms are in the public domain, so use them however you want.  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html